# How to show ranges of repeated values in a colum in Python Pandas?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Does anyone know How to find ranges of repeated categorical values in a column?
I mean, it's something like this:

```
    [Floor]         [Height]
1     A                10
2     A                11
3     A                12
4     B                13
5     B                14
6     C                15
7     C                16
8     A                17
9     A                18
10    C                19
11    C                20
12    B                21
13    B                22
14    B                23
```

What I'm trying to achieve is to determine the Height ranges for each Floor, as shown below:

```
Floor     Height
 A       [10 - 12]
 B       [13 - 14]
 C       [15 - 16]
 A       [17 - 18]
 C       [19 - 20]
 B       [21 - 23]
```

I was trying with pandas.cut() but I can't find the way to set the intervals for repeated values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
(df.groupby(['Floor', 
            (df['Floor']!=df['Floor'].shift()).cumsum().rename('index')])['Height']
  .agg(lambda x: f'{x.min()} - {x.max()}').reset_index(level=0).sort_index())
```

Output:

```
      Floor   Height
index               
1         A  10 - 12
2         B  13 - 14
3         C  15 - 16
4         A  17 - 18
5         C  19 - 20
6         B  21 - 23
```

Answer (score 2):

Another way

```
(df.update((df.astype(str)).groupby((df.Floor!=df.Floor.shift())\
    .cumsum())["Height"].transform(lambda x: x.iloc[0]+'-'+x.iloc[-1])))
    df=df.drop_duplicates()
    print(df)


  Floor Height
1      A  10-12
4      B  13-14
6      C  15-16
8      A  17-18
10     C  19-20
12     B  21-23
```

**How it works**

```
(df.Floor!=df.Floor.shift())#Gives a bolean selection where the first in Floor is not eqal to the immidiate or consecutive last

1      True
2     False
3     False
4      True
5     False
6      True
7     False
8      True
9     False
10     True
11    False
12     True
13    False
14    False
```

(df.Floor!=df.Floor.shift()).cumsum()#gives a new group by cumulatively summing the booleans.Remember True is 1 and Faslse is zero hence the cumulation is by 1

```
1     1
2     1
3     1
4     2
5     2
6     3
7     3
8     4
9     4
10    5
11    5
12    6
13    6
14    6
```

(df.astype(str)).groupby((df.Floor!=df.Floor.shift()).cumsum())#Insetad of using Floor to classify I use the group derived above. Notice I force the df to be of datatype string and this is because I want to concat the heights. This cannot happen unless they are strings

```
(df.astype(str)).groupby((df.Floor!=df.Floor.shift())\
    .cumsum())["Height"].transform(lambda x: x.iloc[0]+'-'+x.iloc[-1])#I use lambda in transform to concat the heights. You concat strings using +. In this case I introduce - between the heights by simply string + '-'+string

1     10-12
2     10-12
3     10-12
4     13-14
5     13-14
6     15-16
7     15-16
8     17-18
9     17-18
10    19-20
11    19-20
12    21-23
13    21-23
14    21-23
#You notice transform appends values to each row hence I have to drop duplicates later.
#Before dropping duplicates, I have to append the new datframe above to the original.
df.update(newframe above)#  gives overwrites the Height with the concatenated heights
df=df.drop_duplicates()#I however have to drop duplicates hence
```

Comment: Cool! I'm kind of new with many Pandas functions, and your answer is very useful, thanks for sharing this other quick method @wwnd! I have some stuff to learn about it.

Comment: Happy to hear. I can break it down further if you needed

Comment: See my edits for a bit of explanation. Happy to help further

Answer (score 0):

For those interested, based on @Scott Boston and @wwnde answers.

Just in case you need the ranges in the same row, if you add to both:

```
df = df[['Floor','Height']] 
pd.DataFrame(df.groupby('Floor')['Height'].unique())
```

The output will be:

```
Floor           Height
 A      [10 - 12, 17 - 18]
 B      [13 - 14, 21 - 23]
 C      [15 - 16, 19 - 20]
```

Thanks you for your help, and special thanks to @wwnde for that nice explanation.